# boost tire results based on time from now

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I use tire for searching in a rails app. Assuming i have these values in the index:

```
-- value       -- time
red shoes      3 weeks ago
red car        yesterday
red blue car   6 months ago
```

How can i boost the results so a search for `red` will display the most recent value?

1. red car
2. red shoes
3. red blue car

It is not as simple as sorting by time because a search for `red blue` should return

1. red blue car (even though it is old, the fact that is has 2 search terms should outweigh  other's freshness)
2. red car
3. red shoes

i realize i could always re-order the results after tire has looked them up, but i was just wondering if tire could do it for me. I feel i would have to pass a `Proc` to `:boost` because `Time.now` would have to be evaluated at search time - but i don't think `:boost` can accept a `Proc`.

```ruby
mapping(:date_detection => false) do
  indexes :id, :index => :not_analyzed
  indexes :label, :type => 'string', :analyzer => :label_analyzer
  indexes :booked_date, :type => 'date', :index => :not_analyzed
end

def self.search(q)
  tire.search do
    query do
      boolean do
        should { string "label:#{q}", boost: -> { #use Time.now and :booked_date to determine a boost } }
      end
    end
    # sort { by :booked_date, 'desc'}
  end
end
```

**UPDATE** based on accepted answer. this does the trick:

---

```ruby
def self.search(q)
  tire.search do
    query do
      boolean do
        should { string "label:#{q}" }
        should { range :booked_date, { from: "now-6M", boost: 4}}
        should { range :booked_date, { from: "now-3M", boost: 5}}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

thanks

Comment: elasticsearch allows to script your scores: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-score-query/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know tire, but a query like this will do what you are asking, but you will have to define the time periods yourself.

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [{ //your query goes here }]
    "should": [
      {
         "range": {
           "timefield": {
             "from": "now-1d",
             "boost": 3.0
           }
         }
      },
      {
         "range": {
           "timefield": {
             "from": "now-1w",
             "boost": 2.0
           }
         }
      },
      {
         "range": {
           "timefield": {
             "from": "now-1M",
             "boost": 1.0
           }
         }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[Have a look at the docs for date math expressions](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/date-format/)

Good luck!